# Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, qt-creator

I just installed Qt 5.5 and am using Qt Creator for the first time on OS X.  When I first installed Qt, it gave me an error message 'Xcode 5 not installed' which I thought was strange, (I have the Xcode 7 beta), but the install completed successfully anyways.

Now, when I start or open a project, I get the error:

> Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.

When I run `/usr/bin/xcodebuild` in Terminal, I get the following:

> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

I'm not sure what Xcode has to do with Qt Creator, unless it has something to do with accessing libraries for cross-platform compatibility, but is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Note: For Qt 5.7.1 and Xcode 8.2.1 the answer by @rudolf-ratusinski however does the job perfectly. Accepted answer does not work.

Comment: @rudolf-ratusinski answer still works on Xcode 11.2.1

Answer (score 279, accepted):

**>= Xcode 8**

In Xcode 8, as Bruce said, this happens when Qt tries to find `xcrun` when it should be looking for `xcodebuild`.

Open the file:

```
Qt_install_folder/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf
```

Replace:

```
isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun 2>/dev/null")))
```

With:

```
isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild 2>/dev/null")))
```

**~> Xcode 8**

Before Xcode 8, this problem occurs when command line tools are installed after Xcode is installed.  What happens is the `Xcode-select` developer directory gets pointed to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Point `Xcode-select` to the correct Xcode Developer directory with the command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Confirm the license agreement with the command:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

This will prompt you to read through the license agreement.

Enter `agree` to accept the terms.

Comment: I got the error xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Xcode 8. I have accepted the license via these instructions and still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks, with XCode 8 after editing default_pre.prf it works !

Comment: For the Xcode>=8 segment, if you are building Qt from a source tree, you also need to patch the `configure` file similarly. The commit which fixes this issue in Qt is https://codereview.qt-project.org/gitweb?p=qt/qtbase.git;a=commitdiff;h=77a71c32c9d19b87f79b208929e71282e8d8b5d9

Comment: For those wondering where is the installation folder: it will depend on your package manager's settings: /usr/local/Cellar/qt55 for Homebrew, /opt/local/libexec/qt5(-mac) for macports.

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to install py35-PyQt5 from macports. The edit to default_pre.prf suggested in this answer fixed the error for me. Note that (as mentioned by yogodoshi above) for macports the file to edit is /opt/local/libexec/qt5/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf

Comment: With homebrew, after installing qt@5.5 (which is required for the Ruby capybara gem), I found the relevant `default_pre.prf` file at: `/usr/local/Cellar/qt@5.5/5.5.1/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf`. I also tried Rudolf Ratusiński's approach, and while it got me over the first hump, it resulted in numerous spurious messages later that I did not get when I used this approach instead.

Comment: dont forget to add ': \' at the end

Comment: @Ricardo Stuven I Opened the file "default_pre.prf" but found that the line is already set correctly. then I tried the `xcode-select -switch` command but I got "invalid developer directory error".

Answer (score 84):

If you change content of `Qt_install_folder/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf`
then it will work only for Desktop kit, not for ex. simulator.

A better way is just to create symlink:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
sudo ln -s xcodebuild xcrun
```

so you don't have to change .prf files for all targets.

Comment: I prefer this version, so it looks less messy than editing cfg files.

Comment: This causes problems later when xcrun is invoked with parameters not supported by xcodebuild (missing parameter -f).

Comment: It seems a qt issue. So I consider more dangerous adding a lasting sym link inside xcode distrib than changing a qt conf file that will be replaced by Qt 5.7.1

Comment: Don't do this, it mess up my iphone app project.

Comment: I upvoted this too soon and got it locked in... I ran into the parameter -f issue.

Comment: I didn't read the comments before I ran the commands. How can you undo this? I dont see any issues, but im afraid I will months from now. Not sure how to test if this caused an issue for me.

Comment: To remove it 
sudo rm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: This worked great. There definitely is a missing parameter -f problem, but I couldn't get .prf changes to stick, so going to just deal with it for now.

Answer (score 27):

This will do the trick:

```
#sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Run this in your terminal.

Comment: works in Xcode8 and easier than the other steps. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed it works on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 with Xcode 8 - Thank you!

Comment: This is still working on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 with Xcode 9.4.1 - Thank you!

Comment: Confirmed this works in macOS Catalina 10.15.2 with Xcode 11.3.

Answer (score 12):

For users of Xcode 8, there is another problem. See here for a temporary solution until Qt 5.7.1 is released:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/71119/project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly

To summarise:

Open `Qt_install_folder/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf` in a text editor, and replace this:

```
isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun 2>/dev/null"))))
```

with this:

```
isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild 2>/dev/null")))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you build Qt from source with XCode 8.x, you have to change the "-find" argument in the file `qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.7.0/qtbase/configure` on line 551 so that it looks like:

```
if ! /usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed to solve it installing the full version of Xcode, agreeing to the terms, then using `xcode-select --reset`.

Basically the problem is that the xcode you're pointing at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` doesn't allow you to accept the terms & conditions. So after the install & resetting the location, all should be OK

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only way to work correctly is to commenting the lines about xcrun with the '#':

```
# Make sure Xcode is set up properly
#isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun 2>/dev/null"))): \
    #error("Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.")
```

At the file: Qt_install_folder/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf

Answer (score -2):

Just to add a bit to a lot of old answers in the spirit of "This worked for me"
I found that by launching Xcode, logging in to my developer account (just a free one) and then setting the Command tools in "Locations". 
I could get the

'sudo /usr/bin/xcodebuild -license agree'

to work. i.e. it launched an agree process in the command line and I agreed after careful reading of all 14 squillion pages of stuff.

I did not have to edit anything.

My system is Mojave 10.14.6 and Xcode 10.3 (10G8).

Comment: If you are going to neg an answer, at least have the courtesy to give a clue as to why!