# XCode 8 error "Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly", even though the license has been accepted

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

I can no longer build Qt project after updating to Xcode 8 today. I get the following error despite having followed the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098040/634821).

> Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the
>   license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I managed to get capybara-webkit (which uses QT) built with XCode 8 / MacOX Sierra after following these instructions (found here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/71119/project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly/7)

1. Move to the folder where you install Qt.
2. Open in a text editor the file at Qt_install_folder/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf
3. Find the line with text (for me it was line 15):

   ```
   isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun 2>/dev/null")))): \
   ```

   Replace line with:

   ```
   isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild 2>/dev/null"))): \
   ```
4. Save & re-compile

Comment: I tried equivalent for iOS. Must I upgrade from **El Capitan 10.11.6** to **macOS** ?  I am getting **Project ERROR: Current iphoneos SDK version (10.0) is too old. Please upgrade Xcode.**

Comment: On my Mac I found the same file at the following location: `qt_install_folder/4.8.7_2/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf`

Comment: It works with QT5.5 installed with brew, same issue with capybara-webkit

Comment: Same issue here for iOS builds but instead of entering "clang_64" I had enter "ios" instead (Rest of the path the same) and edit the "default_pre.prf " file.

Comment: step 2. `[Qt_install_folder]/[Qt_version(/clang_64||)/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf`

Comment: This seemed to get QT5.5 + Mojave + capybara-webkit built.

Comment: This answer depends on your qt version. I found the problem line in `qtbase/configure` on qt 5.3.2, made the change, and got past the issue.

Answer (score 40):

A cleaner solution

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
sudo ln -s xcodebuild xcrun
```

Update 2023:
If you get `ln: xcrun: Operation not permitted`

Settings -> Privacy and Security -> App Managements -> Terminal to ON

Comment: Beautiful solution

Comment: Worked for me on 10.11.6

Comment: Nice! Thanks, it worked for me on 10.12.4 after trying many other solutions.

Comment: Worked on 10.4.2 with qt5.5

Answer (score 0):

Run MaintenanceTool in Qt directory and update to version 5.8