# Qt does not work since Xcode 8

Tags: qt, xcode8

Since Xcode 8 installation, i got this error when creating Qt Console Project:

> Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.

I have re installed Qt and Qt Creator.
I have read a lot of similar post, run xcode-select and stuff.
This is crazy, there is nothing to do, still same error.

I am wondering what Qt exactly do with Xcode ?

(this is Qt 5.7)

Comment: Did you, for example, try running that command and accepting the license agreement?

Comment: [This topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t) describes the problem solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 8 error "Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly", even though the license has been accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492617/xcode-8-error-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-even-though-the-licens)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the moment, untill Qt updates this is a fix:

**Step 1**:

Open the file:

```
<Qt installation folder>/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf
```

**Step 2**:

Replace:

```
isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun 2>/dev/null")))
```

With:

```
isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild 2>/dev/null")))
```

Comment: If you are building Qt from a source tree, you also need to patch the `configure` file similarly. The commit which fixes this issue in Qt is https://codereview.qt-project.org/gitweb?p=qt/qtbase.git;a=commitdiff;h=77a71c32c9d19b87f79b208929e71282e8d8b5d9

Comment: Is this fixed in Qt 5.9 ?

Comment: @HAL9000-Kernel I didn't try yet. I'll let you know if I do.

Answer (score 22):

To avoid error *'Current iPhone SDK version (10.0) is too old. Please upgrade Xcode.'* when building for iOS you need beside changing 'xcrun' to 'xcodebuild' (as says [Luca Angioloni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545797)) also change minimum sdk version to "10.0". Open file:

```
<Qt installation folder>/5.7/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/features/sdk.prf
```

And replace:

```
lessThan(QMAKE_MAC_SDK_VERSION, "8.0"):
```

With:

```
lessThan(QMAKE_MAC_SDK_VERSION, "10.0"):
```

**UPD:** Qt 5.7.1 have already worked with xcode 8 well, just update your Qt to this (or higher) version

Answer (score 8):

Just to complete the answer of Yevgeniy Logachev, you have to use the solution of Luca but for the iOS path, if you want to compile for iOS devices :

`<Qt installation folder>/5.7/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf`

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Luca is correct, this is a Qt bug and more details can be found here:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55649

Including progress on the release/fix.

Comment: You may want to suggest this as an edit to the correct answer rather than adding another answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer