# Qt iOS running fails

Tags: ios, qt, qt-creator

When I try to run my app on iOS simulator, in *Application Output* I see `Starting remote process. Run ended.` When I try to run it on my iPhone, in *Issues* I see `xcodebuild failed`. However, in both ways I have correct XCode projects and can run them myself. It's not so bad, but how can I repair the process?

I also had some problems with Qt and iOS before, solved it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098040/5308802) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39927249/5308802) answers.

My software:
Qt - 5.6.0
Qt Creator - 3.6.1
XCode - 8.0
MacOS - 10.12

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Yoric nope. But Qt generates correct Xcode project, so, you can easily run it yourself. It's not so comfortable, but also not so terrible. As for me, I decided to develop a native application.

Comment: Yes, I'm running from Xcode. It's just disappointing. Especially since *sometimes*, QtDevelop manages to launch it by itself.