# Setup iOS icon from Qt

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, qt-creator

Because of [this unsolved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39996061/5308802) I have to assemble my Qt Creator projects to Xcode projects and run it there. So, I need to setup icon for iOS app version. I tried two ways:

---

1.
I can add icons and *Info.plist* inside ready Xcode project. It works pretty well, but I have no desire to do that every time I assemble Qt project to Xcode project.

---

2.
Thus, I tried to add icons and *plist* to *pro*-file:

```
ios {
    ios_icon.files = $$files($$PWD/ios/AppIcon*.png)
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += ios_icon
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ios/Info.plist
}
```

This way I get incorrect Xcode project. There is no *Info.plist* in the files of project tree, however I have references to that file (in the folder of Qt project, it's not copied) in `Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist file`. App icons of different size are presented in Xcode project, but they are references, not copies. When trying to run, I get:

> Installation failed. Invalid argument.

After coping icons and *plist* to that project, it runs well, but application title is `${PRODUCT_NAME}`.

I also tried to setup copying of *Info.plist* in *pro*-file [these ways](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/61070-Info-plist-is-not-copied), but got the same results.

---

Does anybody know what is going on here??

Comment: It's possible that it's a qmake bug. If so, you'd need to prepare a debug build of Qt for your host, and examine what exactly qmake is doing when generating the Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Xcode bulid file and go to build **Settings>product bundle identifier** . Now set any bundle id in the field . Now run the project , it will automatically  create info.plist file and other set up like standard .

Comment: Thanks, I can add icon to an existing Xcode project, but I need a way to make that in Qt project, because it generates new Xcode project every compilation.

Comment: I am facing same problem , But we can edit in Qt editor and compile & run on IOS Simulator .

Comment: If you find the solution , please help me with that .