# (Already did study but still) Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly

Tags: xcode, qt, qt-creator

Others encounters the same problem of building Qt5.7 on XCode8.0 which gives out

```
Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.
```

And I did follow this answer to change to xcodebuild and I also agreed the license:

[Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t#)

However I still get the same error when building.

One different thing is that instead of downloading XCode from AppStore I downloaded XCode from Apple Deleveloper's site. I am not allowed to login to AppStore in my office.

I can build Xcode applications by it alone.

Does anyone have any ideas?

MacOS 10.12

XCode 8.0

Qt 5.7

Comment: "I am not allowed to login to AppStore in my office." Your office is preventing you from doing your job. You might want to have a word with them :/

Comment: Does `c++ --version` work from the terminal? If not, does `sudo c++ --version` work? If not, try fixing the permissions from disk utility and try again.

Comment: `c++ --version` works fine. Yes I'd need to talk to them. But for today the only thing I can do is to downgrade to 7.3.1 to have a try. Thanks

Comment: My gut feeling is that `which c++` won't show Apple's compiler, or will show different compiler than Qt Creator ends up using. **Do not downgrade anything**. There's really not much to what Qt Creator does: it runs qmake on the project, followed by make or maybe gmake. All the output is available. You should be able to create a build folder for the project, `cd` there, run your chosen Qt's `qmake path/to/sources` followed by `make` and it will either work or it'll be obvious what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug:

[QTBUG-56004](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56004)

Greetings
Marco