# installing qt on macOS Sierra

Tags: xcode, qt, macos-sierra

I have installed qt creator to my mac and I need to configure it. However when I run the configure file I get the error:

Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license
   agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild without arguments.

I have Xcode 8.0. When I run xcodebuild with double-clicking on it I get the error:

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/Onurcan does not contain an Xcode project.

I tried every solution on the web. I would be very appreciated for any help.

Comment: "However when I run the configure file..." What configure file? Are you trying to install Qt, or build it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t/35098040#35098040 duplicate !