# Install Qt on MacOS Sierra with Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, xcode8

I am trying to install Qt with Xcode 8. I'm having the error

> Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license
>      agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild without arguments.

and I found this solution: [Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t/40528851?noredirect=1#comment68298881_40528851)
. Problem is, that I don't have it installed from before, so there is no installation folder nor file to edit. Any solutions?

Comment: Try opening Xcode, it should display the license agreement the first time you run it.

Comment: Forgot to say! License is already accepted.