# iOS kit not detected on Qt (macOS)

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I am currently trying to port an android application on iOS. The application was developped on Linux. But I can't manage to use Qt on macOs for iOS developpement.

I followed those (rather unclear) instructions : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios-support.html

First, I installed successfully XCode and I managed to deploy a dummy app on my iPhone. Then, I installed Qt and opened the ".pro" project file.
But the only kit I can use is "Desktop Qt 5.4.1 clang 64 bit". The kits for iOS don't seem to be detected.

Did I do something wrong ? Am I missing something ?

EDIT:

When I launch the ".pro", I got this error :

```
Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.
```

Unfortunately, it is NOT related to this well known issue ([Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t))

When I run the command :

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

I get this error:

```
xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/<UserName> does not contain an Xcode project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to solve my problem by re installing Qt with version 5.8 (instead of 5.9.1).

But I am not sure this is what was causing the issue though. In deed, I realized I installed Qt prior to configuring XCode the first time(with my Developer Account).